# Repetitive task for web requests

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

My app needs to communicate with a server.

> I have a couple of different requests (and some of them needs to be
>   repetitive (request made -> resp receive -> another req made -> ...))

What I need to use (task maybe?) to perform a request-response communication? I need a req to be made while the user is logged in (each req made after a previous response)

In java I would use a worker thread which performs a request and after that I would call wait() on that thread and when the response comes, I will wake up the thread(with notify()) and make another req and so on... What is the equivalent for c# - windows store apps

Comment: Have you looked at [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)?

Comment: No I haven't. I looked into this and seems the "await" is what I was looking for. Thank you.